# Why does the Flutter app gets restarted upon setting a wallpaper?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, wallpapermanager

I have made a wallpaper app using Flutter. I have used the below package to help user set the wallpaper as HOME, LOCK or BOTH screens. But after setting any image to wallpaper, the whole app gets restarted.

[image: package ss]

```
Future<void> _setwallpaper(imagePath, location) async {
    var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(imagePath);

   
      WallpaperManagerFlutter().setwallpaperfromFile(file, location);

   }
```

I tried other packages like wallpaper and flutter_wallpaper_manager. However, the same issue exists with these packages as well.

How can I prevent a restart of the flutter app upon setting a wallpaper?

Comment: Provide your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes i have shared the code